# How to implement this kind of list

Tags: android

My app is a client for a freeware PC-based PVR application which allows the user to view a TV Guide and select TV shows to record and send a request to their own PC to schedule the recording (or cancel a previously scheduled recording).

One of my users has requested a feature to show all shows / all channels in a vertical list with shows divided by a 'timeslot' indicator / divider. They provided an example image as below...

[image]

My problem is I can't work out what sort of list that would be using. It seems in theory I can do this with a standard ListView and a custom adapter but I'm also wondering about ExpandableListView as those timeslot indicators / dividers could perhaps be implemented as group dividers.

I've never worked with ExpandableListView however so I'm not sure if that's how it works and it suggests all groups will need to be expanded by default.

I've done a lot of reading on both classes and looked at a variety of sample code on the Android developer web site but I still can't work out what approach to take. I'm sure I've seen a similar question on SO but can't find it to see what the answer was. Any pointers gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bet for ExpandableListView; though it could be a regular ListView with two types of view, one for the separators and one for regular items.